# Google Apps Script won't validate my IF statement

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can't figure this one out in a timely fashion and maybe secretly hoping someone will tell me I'm going about this the wrong way and maybe suggest a better way.  I have a script that's activated by highlighting a range of cells and clicking a button.  There's some error checking that goes on first to make sure the selection is good, then this is the actual guts of the code.  Everything works well, the only bug I can't seem to solve is that the if statements won't return positive, so they just get skipped and the code finishes with no actual action performed.  I've commented below the expected data from each variable.  Pls halp!

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sA1 = source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
var sdata = source.getRange(sA1).getValues();
var samtpaid = source.getRange(sA1).offset(0, 8, sdata.length, 1).getValues();
var sdate = source.getRange("J2").getValue();


var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...sheetid...").getSheetByName("...sheetname...");
```

Target spreadsheet has all the data in sdata and many more records that are not contained in sdata.

```
  var trange = target.getDataRange();
  var tvalues = target.getDataRange().getValues();
  var trangesize = target.getDataRange().getLastRow();

    for (var i = 0; i < sdata.length; ++i) {
  var row = sdata[i];
  var row2 = samtpaid[i];
  var row3 = sdate;

    for (var j = 0; j < trangesize; ++j) {
  var trow = tvalues[j];

  if (row[0] == trow[0]){
```

row[0] is a timestamp, so is trow[0]... when debugging with a msgBox, the values appeared to be exactly alike (when it finds the record that matches), this is why I can't figure out what the deal is.

```
  if (row[6] == trow[1]){
```

row[6] is an email address, so is trow[1]... code never made it to this if statement to see if it would pass, but the values appear to be exact matches

```
  trange.offset(0, 17, 1, 1).setValues(row2[i]);
  trange.offset(0,18,1,1).setValue(row3);

    } //end inner if

    } //end outer if

    } //end inner for

  } //end outer For
```

Comment: Try checking the string values of each variable by using `row[6].toString()` to compare the text itself.

Comment: @BrianBennett Thanks very much, that works.  Is there any explanation as to why this is required? I'm comparing the autogenerated timestamp cell to a timestamp cell on another sheet... seems like it should work either way.

Comment: `.getValues()` returns an Object. In JavaScript, Object equality is memory-referenced, not value referenced. So, the strings are equal, but their place in memory is different, returning false. [This article](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html) has a great explanation.

Comment: I just had a read, thanks a bunch for linking that article, was worth knowing :)  Have a good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (row[0].toString() == trow[0].toString()){
if (row[6] == trow[1]){
```

Minor update was all it needed. Rather than compare dates/times, comparing strings was the way to go.

```
trange.offset(j,17,1,1).setValue(row2);
trange.offset(j,18,1,1).setValue(row3);
```

Minor update here where i didn't need the row2[i], just row2 was enough.  Also using j (instead of 0) as numRows offset meant the value got appended to the right place, as opposed to just the top row and overwrite itself each time the code looped.

Thanks for the help!